# Backtracking chopsticks in java

Tags: java, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I have an exercise that is killing my brain; which is:
I have x sticks, and I break them into x chunks which I measure, they are a vector of numbers, the solution to the problem is to find the minimum number to create sticks of the same size:

Sample input

```
9

5 2 1 5 2 1 5 2 1

4

1 2 3 4

0 (this is the end of the input it have to be there)
```

Sample output

```
6

5
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get a good answer to your question, it's important to be specific about the problem you're running into. Your question currently doesn't actually ask a question: it just says you have an exercise that you're struggling with. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking a good question, and refine this question accordingly.

Comment: "...the solution to the problem is to find the minimum number to create sticks of the same size" - have you tried to make algorithm for this ? once your logic is ready, you can go for implementation. Then finally post your code sample to https://codereview.stackexchange.com for further assistance